# PPA purge does not seem to remove the PPA?

Tags: 16.04, apt, ppa, purge

I did:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
```

and got:

```
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.....]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

When I look in software and updates-> other software, the PPA is still there, and also in the `sources.list.d` folder, but not in the `sources.list` file.

I realised that the W: part is because the PPA is not compatible with `xenial`. But I still don't what the two E: parts mean, and how to purge the PPA.

I can remove manually, but I want to make sure I have purged all associated files etc, as it is the third party, and I don't want anything dodgy staying on my computer...? I'm a noob btw, so maybe a bit ignorant on this...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you really running an Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) system?

Comment: Yes, I need to upgrade it!

Comment: Unless you installed some package using that PPA, there should be no file related to that PPA in your system except APT cache which would be deleted on next `apt update`.

Comment: Did that PPA **ever** work for you since 2016? Did you ever successfully install any SDL packages from it? Or did it give you a mysterious error every time you tried?

Comment: Ok thank you. So if I remove the PPA from software & updates, and from sources.list.d folder manually there's no way of anything nasty being leftover on my computer...? And the updating packages list should return to normal..?!

Comment: I never used the PPA, I just downloaded it in the last few days, and then realised I didn't need it

Comment: Just to be sure, you can do "sudo apt-get update" then "sudo apt-cache policy" to make sure that it isn't included in your apt database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with two items:

- The name of the PPA: [SDL2 Backport to Bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecybermax-dexter/+archive/ubuntu/sdl2-backport).
- Your release from the PPA URL you provided: Xenial (which is not Bionic)

From these two facts, we can draw a conclusion: **The 18.04 PPA is unlikely to have provided any usable packages to your 16.04 system**.

The corollary to that conclusion is that the PPA has perhaps never worked for you, and has only returned error messages every time you tried.

---

**How to check for the PPA files on your system**:

1. The list of the 10 packages and versions provided by the PPA is [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecybermax-dexter/+archive/ubuntu/sdl2-backport/+packages)
2. Use `apt-cache policy <package_name>` to check the source and version number of  each of the listed packages. If the package version and source match the PPA, uninstall the package.

Here's an example:

```
$ apt-cache policy hello             <--- The example page name is "hello"
hello:
  Installed: 2.10-2ubuntu2           <--- Version number. Should EXACTLY match the version number provided by the PPA
  Candidate: 2.10-2ubuntu2            +-- Sources. The PPA should be listed as a source. 
  Version table:                      V
 *** 2.10-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

**Deleting the PPA**:

There are two steps to deleting a PPA:

- Uninstall the packages (you did this in the section above)
- Delete the apt source , so apt doesn't re-install the packages

You already found the apt source: A file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. Delete that file: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<filename>`. You can also use your Software & Sources control panel to delete the PPA source.

Good practice is to run an apt-update after making any change to your apt sources: `sudo apt-get update`. The update should have no errors or warnings.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer :) I searched for those packages e.g. 'apt search "aom"', and none of those packages seem to be in apt except a couple with different versions so assuming they never got downloaded due to being for Bionic

Comment: For future- are only the exact packages shown on Launchpad able to be downloaded from that repository? If the source is not trusted, can they theoretically disguise malware etc as something else? And would someone with 500 karma usually be a trustworthy source?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, theoretically. There are several reasons that doesn't happen. 3) Yes.